# Pause and Play CAKeyFrameAnimation in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, cabasicanimation, cakeyframeanimation

I'm doing animation for calayer using CAkeyframeanimation.Actually i`m moving the calayer using the position property by using the CAkeyframeanimation.I want to pause the calayer moving animation.When i tap the screen it should resumes from where it paused.

I added two animations for a calayer.One is for changing the bounds property of the calayer another one is position property.so i am using two animation for a single calayer but i want to pause the position property animation of the calayer util i tap the screen. After i tapped it should resumes from the paused position.

I used the following code but it stops all animations which i applied to the calayer.

```
      - (void) pauseLayer: (CALayer *) theLayer
       {  
         CFTimeInterval mediaTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
         CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [theLayer convertTime: mediaTime fromLayer: nil];
         theLayer.speed = 0.0;
         theLayer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
        }

         - (void) removePauseForLayer: (CALayer *) theLayer;
         {
           theLayer.speed = 1.0;
           theLayer.timeOffset = 0.0;
           theLayer.beginTime = 0.0;
         }
         - (void) resumeLayer: (CALayer *) theLayer;
         {
           CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [theLayer timeOffset];
           [self removePauseForLayer: theLayer];
           CFTimeInterval mediaTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
           CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [theLayer convertTime: mediaTime fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
           theLayer.beginTime = timeSincePause;

          }
```

I also tried the remove animation property of the CAanimtion.It works!! but i cant able to resume the animation from the paused the position.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: [Apple's technical note QA1673 describes how to pause/resume layer's animation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2009/qa1673.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already seen that post.Thank you very much.But i didnt found the solution Please help me

Comment: updated Apple link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1673/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010053